# Saving dynamically added divs containing charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, javascript-objects

I have a page that is capable of charting multiple csv files through highcharts with an add button that dynamically creates a div that then charts the file. The problem is that I need to save it so that when the page reloads, the multiple charts added stays and does not get refreshed. A delete all button is also included so it removes all the dynamically added divs.

I have currently tried localStorage.getitem however it does not replicate the graph created with all its functionality, just an image.

https://jsfiddle.net/j_darmawan/m5vcu08e/

```
$('#super').html(window.localStorage.getItem('content'));

$('#delete').click(function() {
  localStorage.removeItem('content');
  alert('removed');
  $('#container').empty();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  var html = $('#super').html();
  window.localStorage.setItem('content', html);
  alert('saved');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to save the data in local storage of browser and retrive the same while reload

Storing data in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('chart_'+count, JSON.stringify(storeData));
```

Here count is incremented value to store the multiple charts data in localStorage.

Retrieving data from localStorage:

```
var dynamicData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart_'+i));
```

Since we are storing JSON object it needs to be parse again while fetching it.

Code is working in fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jk25L9er/

Since there is CORS issue in StackOverflow code is tested in jsfiddle

```js
 

           var defaultData = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j-darmawan/Charting/master/samplebar.csv';
var urlInput = document.getElementById('fetchURL');
var pollingCheckbox = document.getElementById('enablePolling');
var pollingInput = document.getElementById('pollingTime');
var count = 1;
 //localStorage.clear();
console.log(localStorage);
$(function(){
  var numbercnt = 1;
  $('button.add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(numbercnt);
    createChart('',numbercnt);
  })
  function createChart(dynamicData = '',number ='') {
    $('#super').append('<div id="bton"><button type="button" class="design_button" id="chart_'+number+'">Remove chart below</button><div id="settings'+number+'"></div></div>');
    
    if(dynamicData == ''){

      var storeData = {
        'csvURL' : urlInput.value,
        'enablePolling' : pollingCheckbox.checked === true,
        'dataRefreshRate' : parseInt(pollingInput.value, 10),
        'firstRowAsNames' : false,
      };
      localStorage.setItem('chart_'+number, JSON.stringify(storeData));
    }else{
      var storeData = dynamicData;
      numbercnt = localStorage.getItem('chart_total');
    }

    var chartData = {
      csvURL: storeData.csvURL,
      enablePolling:storeData.enablePolling,
      dataRefreshRate: storeData.dataRefreshRate,
      firstRowAsNames: storeData.firstRowAsNames,
      complete: function(csv) {
        csv.series[0].data.forEach(function(point, i) {
          csv.series[0].data[i] = {
            x: point[0],
            y: point[1],
            customInfo: csv.series[1].data[i][1]
          }

        })
        csv.series.pop()
      }
    };


    Highcharts.chart('settings' + number,{
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Sample' + ' Slip'
      },
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
        second: '%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M',
        hour: '%H:%M',
        day: '%e. %b',
        week: '%e. %b',
        month: '%b \'%y',
        year: '%Y'
      },
      data: chartData,
      series: [{
        name: 'Slip'
      }],

      yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          color: 'black',
          width: 2,
          zIndex: 1
        }]

      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          color: 'red',
          negativeColor: 'green'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>Last Updated: <b>{point.customInfo}</b>'


      }
    });



    if (pollingInput.value < 1 || !pollingInput.value) {
      pollingInput.value = 1;
    }


    numbercnt++;
    localStorage.setItem('chart_total', numbercnt);

  }
  $('#super').on('click','button.design_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    // Remove from localstorage 2019-09-12 11:50:03
    localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr("id")); 
  });
  function loadDynamicData(){
    var length =  localStorage.getItem('chart_total');
    for(var i =1;i<=length ;i++){
      if(localStorage.getItem('chart_'+i)){
        var dynamicData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart_'+i));
        console.log(dynamicData)
        createChart(dynamicData,i);
      }
    }
  }
  loadDynamicData();
});


urlInput.value = defaultData;

// We recreate instead of using chart update to make sure the loaded CSV
// and such is completely gone.
// pollingCheckbox.onchange = urlInput.onchange = pollingInput.onchange = createChart;

// Create the chart
//createChart();
```

```css
.ld-label {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ld-row {}

.ld-url-input {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Slip Charting</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <h1>Slip Charting</h1>
    <div class="ld-row">
      <label class="ld-label">
        Enable Polling
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="enablePolling" />
    </div>
<div class="ld-row">
      <label class="ld-label">
        Polling Time (Seconds)
      </label>
      <input class="ld-time-input" type="number" value="2" id="pollingTime" />
    </div>
<div class="ld-row">
      <label class="ld-label">
        Project Number
      </label>
      <input class="ld-url-input" type="text" id="fetchURL" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add" class="design_button add">Draw</button>

<div id ="super">
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It does half of what I need it to do, as after refreshing the page, I don't see a way of removing the charts individually and for it to be reused again.  For example, if I drew 3 charts, and then proceed to only need 2 of them, I don't see a way to delete that specific one after I reload the page.

Comment: In your delete logic just remove the same key from  local storage also wait I will update logic for that in answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/do7rb205/
check this fiddle logic to remove from localstorage logic

Comment: Hi again, sorry to ask this after but some of the functionality was lost in the process. For example when I add the charts then refresh the page, the previous charts are there however, when I proceed to add new charts it overwrites the old ones.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but when you add new charts to existing page the new chars don't get saved? The number of total charts counter still goes up even when theres 2 charts remaining.